# Unable to push a branch

Tags: dev

I would like to submit a PR for a feature I am working on. I was able to clone `git@github.com:paritytech/substrate.git`, created a local branch/made the changes, and tried to push the branch (`git push --set-upstream origin <branch name>`). But I run into
`ERROR: Permission to paritytech/substrate.git denied to <user name>` issue

I tried all the usual github trouble shooting steps (created new set of ssh keys, verified authentication, verified
I can read/write other github repos fine, etc). Is there anything else I might be missing? Do new contributors need to be added to any access groups, etc?

[1] https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-to-userrepo-denied-to-other-user

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at the contribution guide

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Answer (score 1):

Just create a fork of Substrate in your own personal account. Then push your work onto there and create a MR back to the paritytech repo.

Comment: Thanks all. I do have a private fork already that I was using for experimenting with, let me use that. For making PRs, the contributing doc is somehow not very clear that patches should go on a private fork.

Comment: Please feel free to submit a PR that makes the contributing doc more clear. That would be really helpful!